# WCF REST GET returns "Endpoint not found"

Tags: c#, rest, wcf

So I am trying to create a very basic WCF service with REST GET but there is only "Endpoint not found". I am sending GET via Postman App to address:

```
http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RESTfulTest/Service1/json
```

Service is hosted by IIS; Here's all my code:

```
namespace RESTfulTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet]
        string GetText();
    }
}

namespace RESTfulTest
{
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode =InstanceContextMode.Single)]
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetText()
        {
            return "Hello REST";
        }
    }

}
```

And App.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="RESTfulTest.Service1">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RESTfulTest/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding"  behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" contract="RESTfulTest.IService1"/>
      </service>
    </services>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So everything was set up properly. The endpoint address that I was asking was incorrect. It should be `http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/RESTfulTest/Service1/json/GetText`
I didn't know that function name should be added to the address, that's the point.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be using ASP.NET Ajax to call the service? If not, you should not be using the `<enableWebScript>` behavior, but rather the `<webHttp>` behavior.

Also, you should probably remove the `<serviceMetadata>` behavior, since you won't be exposing WSDL from your service.

Comment: I have already tried using `<webHttp>` but it did not help. Actually I am going to use WSDL later. The code that I have posted is a simplified version of bigger project, but I stil have problem to make REST service working there. Maybe I don't have permissions or something like that?